# get height of image on load and send to parent

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to get the height of an image when it has loaded and send it back to the parent component, but it is causing infinite rerendering.

This is a prototype of my code:

```
import MyImage from './images/myImage.jpg';

class Image extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            height: 0
        }
    }

    getHeight = (e) => {
        const height = e.target.getBoundingClientRect().height;

        this.setState({
            height: height
        });
        this.props.setUnitHeight(height);
    }


    render() {
        const image = this.props.image;

        return (
            <img src={image.name} onLoad={(e)=>{this.getHeight(e)}} />;
        );
    }
}

class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        const initUnit = 78.4;

        this.state = {
            unit: initUnit
        }
    }

    setUnitHeight = (height) => {
        this.setState({
            unit: height
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
                <div>
                    <Image image={MyImage} setUnitHeight={this.setUnitHeight} />
                </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I have tried sending unit as a prop and then checking in shouldComponentUpdate whether it should be rerender or not, but that did nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are having is that React by default re-renders the component every time you call `this.setState`. In your case what this is happening:

- You load your `Image` component
- It loads the `<img>` tag and fires the `onLoad` function
- The `onLoad` function calls `this.setState`
- Repeat these steps forever

You should take a look at the React's lifecycle components methods (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle) to understand this better.

My suggestion is: do not keep the image height in the state, unless you really need it. If you really need to maintain it in the state for some reason you can use the lifecycle method `shouldComponentUpdate` (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate`) to prevent it from rendering.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and clarifying what is happening. I tried using `shouldComponentUpdate` with `return nextState.height !== this.state.height` but that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems redundant, `setState({})` isn't necessary in `<Image>` class. If you are using the same props throughout the app, then you should be setting it at one place and be using the same prop all over. For example -

```
getHeight = (e) => {
    const height = e.target.getBoundingClientRect().height;
    //setState not needed here
    this.props.setUnitHeight(height);
}
```

That should do it.

P.S: Do check if your `this` references aren't going out of scope.